# Why my download speed is just half of the speed given by my Wi-Fi providing device in Ubuntu 20?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, performance, wifi-hotspot

I had just upgraded to Ubuntu 20 (focal fossa). When I try to download anything in any browser or through terminal, the downloading speed in my PC is just half of my Wi-Fi providing device.

Please clarify if it is just my myth or there is some technical error?

And there were no other apps running in background on both devices at that time. The Wi-Fi drivers are the one provided by Ubuntu 20 itself and my laptop is HP 15.

The image is showing the speed given by my WiFi providing device, it's 1.8MB/s

[image: The image is showing the speed given by my WiFi providing device, it's 1.8MB/s]

This image is showing the downloading speed in Firefox. Check the first one it's 792KB/s

[image: This image is showing the downloading speed in Firefox. Check the first one it's 792KB/s]

Comment: Perhaps an obvious question but have you compared download speeds of the same file download from the same website / mirror?  In your screenshot we can't see what's downloading on your phone.  Some Ubuntu mirrors may be slow or your connection to them (across the internet) may be slow.

Comment: If you type "speed test" in Google, you will get their speed checker.  Run that on both your phone and your Ubuntu and compare the results.

Comment: The speed test is almost same in both devices.

Answer (score 0):

The download speed you are currently seeing is not the limit provided by your provider. If you use some network speed monitoring tool, you will notice that value changes continously depending on what network process is running in the background. So assuming you have been provided with 19mbs, when the network traffic is pow you will see a small value in your speed infldicator but when you are having big network usage e.g. downloads, the value will go up depending on whats being downloaded at that time.

It is also good to note that some providers provide different limits for the upload and download speeds. e.g. 10mbs could be defined as 4mbps download and 6mbps upload.